# How to catch "OpenCV Error" in Python

Tags: python, opencv

If I get OpenCV Error: ...

what's the syntax to catch it since OpenCV Error uses two words? I'm able to catch the following cv.error but how would I catch this?

**EDIT:**

I don't get it... is the answer obvious? Am I being unclear?

**EDIT 2**

I can't reproduce it b/c I'm on a different computer but it looked similar to:

`OpenCV Error: Bad argument. Something something array`

`cv.error: This is another error`

I'm able to catch cv.error but not OpenCV Error with the following:

```
try:
    # do a thing
except (cv.error, OpenCV Error):
    print "Can't do the thing"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: What is the exception raised when you run into this OpenCV Error?

Comment: Yes, you're being very unclear. Please explain your problem more clearly. Unfortunately I can't tell you specifically what you should improve in your question, because I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Post the traceback, and if possible the exceptional code

Comment: Some OpenCV functions don't throw errors, they print out a message and exit the program (either with exit or abort, I can't remember). In other words, there are some errors that can't be caught.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try `cv2.error`.

```
try:
    ...
except cv2.error as e:
    ...
```

[Here's](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html?highlight=error) the page from the documentation but it's only for the C/C++ interface -- I can't find anything on the Python error handling for OpenCV (I find the documentation for the Python interface to be sadly lacking).

Answer (score 5):

you can easily inspect the error object, like

```py
fvs = imutils.video.FileVideoStream(args.input).start()

while fvs.more():

  frame = fvs.read()

  try:
    
    grayframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  except cv2.error as e:
    
    # inspect error object
    print(e)
    for k in dir(e):
      if k[0:2] != "__":
        print("e.%s = %s" % (k, getattr(e, k)))

    # handle error: empty frame
    if e.err == "!_src.empty()":
      break # break the while loop
```