# List supported OpenCV video capture properties in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a function that automatically determines which set of video capture properties are supported by a particular webcam. This is simple to do with `v4l2-ctl`, but I don't know how to do it cleanly using OpenCV's built-in functions. Using `v4l2-ctl`, I would invoke:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --device <webcam> --list-ctrls
```

which yields a different set of camera controls for my laptop's integrated webcam (`/dev/video0`) and for whatever USB webcam that I plug in. So far in Python OpenCV, the best I've been able to do is:

```
def list_supported_capture_properties(cap: cv2.VideoCapture):
    """ List the properties supported by the capture device.
    """
    supported = list()
    for attr in dir(cv2):
        if attr.startswith('CAP_PROP'):
            if cap.get(getattr(cv2, attr)) != -1:
                supported.append(attr)
    return supported
```

When this function is called, OpenCV prints out a lot of error messages like these:

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Autofocus is not supported by your device
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: getting property #32 is not supported
```

If I wrap `cap.get` in a Python try statement, the videoio errors above are not caught, so it's as if I had no try-except at all. Specializing the except clause to `cv2.error` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8874487/2738025) doesn't work for me. I could reroute output to dev/null as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669280/2738025), but this seems more like a band-aid than a cure to me.

So, here are my two questions:

1. Is it possible to catch the OpenCV videoio error in Python? How do I do that?
2. Is there a better way to get only the list of *supported* capture properties? Would it be better run `v4l2-ctl` as a subprocess, then process the text in the output to determine the capture properties?

Comment: Thanks for posting this,  ran into the same issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late for the answer, but maybe there are others with the same problem.

That you get different properties is a bug of opencv, which is there since many years. The problem is, that there are two different libraries for v4l2-devices ( v4l2 and libv4l2) . Compiling opencv with libv4l2 leads to these errors.

Question 1: the errors you have seen are not produced by python, but by the underlying opencv c++ code . It seems that hey are directly written to stdout.

Question 2: when you have opencv compiled without libv4l2, then your code should give the exact same list as v4l2-ctl. When working with the corrupted opencv-version
You can not get neither set any of the CAP_PROP parameters.