# Try-Catch Exception won't work in OpenCV-python

Tags: python, opencv

So i purposely put a file in the cv2.VideoCapture() that doesn't exist in my computer to test the try-catch system i've put into my code but for some reason it still gives off the same error it gives when i didn't put a try-catch into my code. how do i fix this??

code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2



try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('trial.mkv')
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
except:
    print("no file found")
```

error:

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cff9bdsm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (142) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cff9bdsm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): trial.mkv in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

Answer (score 2):

I definitely agree @AzyCrw4282 but I also point-out two issues on your code, therefore I'm writing as an answer.

- Issue #1: Use `except cv2.error as error` to catch the error:

---

- ```py
  except cv2.error as error:
      print("[Error]: {}".format(error))
  ```

  Result:
- ```py
  [Error]: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:350: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

  Process finished with exit code 0
  ```
- Even if I give an invalid video file:

  ```py
  OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "trial.mkv"

  Process finished with exit code 0
  ```
- Actually `try-catch` block is working if you use `except cv2.error as error`.
- Issue #2: Please always check frame

---

For instance: If you want to stop the application use:

- ```py
  if frame is None
      break
  ```

  or

  ```py
  ret, frame = cap.read()
      if ret:
          cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
          if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
              break
  ```

  if frame returns then display

Full code:

```py
import cv2

try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('dread.mp4')
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
except cv2.error as error:
    print("[Error]: {}".format(error))

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Glad, if I could help :)

Comment: This doesn't work for remote RTSP urls by the way. E.g if you do ```cv2.VideoCapture('some_remote_rtsp_url')``` then it won't catch any thrown errors.

Answer (score 1):

When an error is caught by the `try/except` statement and `stderr` msg is still printed it just means that the library is simply sending all the error messages to the `stderr`.

`OpenCV` library was known to have this problems and there are ways around it. You should read the detailed answers here - [OpenCv error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49751695/6505847) and [How to stop OpenCV error message from printing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602465/how-to-stop-opencv-error-message-from-printing-in-python)